# My Select state is being updated in the select component, but not his value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

In my application I have **two select** one for the years and another one for the month, when I click on a reset button the status of both is reset to the first ones, in one of the components it restarts but in the **month select** it does not work, I have been thinking about it for a while and I do not see anything strange.

**IMPORTANT, THE STATE OF THE COMPONENT DOES CHANGE, WHAT DOES NOT CHANGE IS THE VALUE OF THE SELECT, THE PREVIOUS MONTH IS STILL SHOWN**

[Select section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQq2k.png)

[Selects components and his props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2bVp.png)

[inside select component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti6Df.png)

[useSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRn4U.png)

I tried to put an useEffect inside the Select.jsx component with a console.log() when the "value" prop changes, but it doesn't show anything, just show the year value

Comment: Can you create sandbox for this?